# Angle subtended by two curves.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the angle made by the curves $y^2=\frac {2x}{\pi},y=\sin(x) $ at point of intersection other than origin . Now I know one is parabola other is sine curve . I also know that they intersect at $(0,0), (\frac {\pi}{2},1) $ .The subtended angle  is also angle between their tangents. So derivatives are $\frac {1}{\pi.y},\cos (x) $. but what do  I do next substitute points?. Now I am lost.

Comment: $\tan\theta=|\dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}|$ where $m$ is slop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: It is known that if two curves $f_1 (x) $ and $f_2 (x) $ intercept at $P (x_0, y_0) $ then the angle between then can be found as $$\tan \phi =\frac {f_2'(x_0)-f_1'(x_0)}{1+f_1'(x_0)f_2'(x_0)} $$ Hope this hint helps.

Comment: Oh so you could apply it for any curve I thought it was only for lines .